# How can I FetchContent with no warnings for developers (with -Wno-dev)?

Tags: c++, cmake, zeromq, cmakelists-options, fetchcontent

I am trying to add `zmq` as a third party library with `FetchContent`.
However, I am uninterested on the warnings meant for devs.
As I have taken the tag for a verified release, it should be working without any errors or warnings ideally.

I do not want to have `-Wno-dev` for my whole CMake project configuration- only for my 3rd party libraries.
I have not found a way to do it inside the `CMakeLists.txt`.

My code for `FetchContent` is:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  libzmq
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.git
  GIT_TAG        v4.3.4
  OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(libzmq)
```

I also didn't find a version that have no warnings since v4.2.2
I have tested with `BUILD_COMMAND` or `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` but I found no solution through reading the documentation of `CMake` nor `FetchContent`

Answer (score 1):

I think you *might* be out of luck. From the FetchContent docs:

> The `<contentOptions>` can be any of the download, update or patch options that the `ExternalProject_Add()` command understands.

Notice how configure and build options are not on that list (Ex. `CMAKE_ARGS`, `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`).

I looked through the list of CMake variables for one with "dev" and "warn" (usually when looking for directory-scoped overrides for these kinds of things, that's what you should do), and didn't find what you're looking for. There was [`CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED.html), but that's not the same (it's for the [`-Wno-deprecated`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-Wno-deprecated)/[`-Wdeprecated`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-Wdeprecated) flags).

Comment: I had already seen the CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED but that doesn't seem to affect the FetchContent either :S 

I also think I am out of luck with this one. Just hoping if anyone does have a solution ;)

Thanks anw

Comment: Is there a better way to add 3rdparty libraries?

gitsubmodules is another approach I was checking, as well as the ExternalProject_Add directly, but I thought FetchContent seemed to be the best.

Comment: @Kikadass it depends what kind of control you want / need. ExternalProject gives you more control than FetchContent at the cost of having to... well- take control.